# Clicking on the 'Read More' button causes to open all blocks instead of its particular parent block

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have to show some feature listing. At initial page load i want to show only three points.
Once i am clicking on the 'Read more' button than  that particular divs rest  feature should be open.

But the problem is that clicking on the 'Read More' button causes to open all the features blocks.

Please consider this html :

```
<div class="parent first-feature">
    <div class="feature-listing">
        <ul>
            <li>Some Content</li>
            <li>Some Content</li>
            <li>Some Content</li>
            <li class="r-more"><a href="JavaScript:void(0);" class="read-more">Read More!</a></li>                
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="more-content" style="display:none;">
        <ul class="feature-listing">                
            <li>Some More Content</li>
            <li>Some More Content</li>
            <li>Some More Content</li>
            <li>Some More Content</li>
            <li>Some More Conten</li>    
            <li class="r-less"><a href="JavaScript:void(0);" class="read-more">Read Less</a></li>                
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="parent second-feature">
    <div class="feature-listing">
        <ul>
            <li>Some Content</li>
            <li>Some Content</li>
            <li>Some Content</li>
            <li class="r-more"><a href="JavaScript:void(0);" class="read-more">Read More!</a></li>                
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="more-content" style="display:none;">
        <ul class="feature-listing">                
            <li>Some More Content</li>
            <li>Some More Content</li>
            <li>Some More Content</li>
            <li>Some More Content</li>
            <li>Some More Conten</li>    
            <li class="r-less"><a href="JavaScript:void(0);" class="read-more">Read Less</a></li>                
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the function which i have write:

```
$('.read-more').click(function(){
    $('.more-content').slideToggle('slow');
    $('.r-more').toggleClass('hide-block');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/zNq2c/)**</kbd>

```
$('.read-more').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.parent').find('.more-content').stop().slideToggle('slow');
  $('.r-more').toggleClass('hide-block');
});
```

Comment: nice answer. but your fiddle doesn't seem to work. If you change jQuery to 2.1.0 in fiddle it works.

Comment: It works perfect in the fiddle. I checked just now, works as it should, don't know why isn't working for you.

Comment: It WORKS with 2.0.2 also!